# My power button doesn't work under LXDE. How can I fix this?

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown, lxde, acpi, logout

Ever since I switched to LXDE my power button won't work anymore. I would love to be able to display a fancy logout menu like the one in Unity and similar DEs. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The ACPID way

---

**Overview**

There are numerous ways of fixing this issue. If you look through the web you will find suggestions on installing power managers used in other desktop environments (DEs) like `xfce4-power-manager` or `gnome-settings-daemon`. However, as an LXDE user you are probably striving for a lightweight solution. One lightweight way to display a logout menu on power button press is to utilize an ACPID script.

**What is ACPID?**

From the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acpid):

> **acpid** is a flexible and extensible daemon for delivering ACPI events.
>   It listens on /proc/acpi/event and when an event occurs, executes
>   programs to handle the event. These events are triggered by certain
>   actions, such as:
>
> - Pressing special keys, including the Power/Sleep/Suspend button
> - Closing a notebook lid (Un)Plugging an AC power adapter from a    notebook
> - (Un)Plugging phone jack etc.

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-get install acpi acpid
```

**Configuration**

Open `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` in a text editor of your choice, e.g. leafpad:

```
gksudo leafpad /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
```

At the end of the file you will find the following passage:

```
# If all else failed, just initiate a plain shutdown.
/sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
```

Just before this passage add the following snippet:

```
# If LXDE is running execute lxsession-logout
if [ -n $(pidof lxsession) ]; then
    for x in /tmp/.X11-unix/*; do
       displaynum=`echo $x | sed s#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##`
       getXuser;
       if [ x"$XAUTHORITY" != x"" ]; then
           export DISPLAY=":$displaynum"
           export _LXSESSION_PID=`pidof lxsession`
           lxsession-logout
           exit
       fi
    done
fi
```

Most of the snippet consists of functions and commands that make sure that a graphical application like the logout menu can be run by ACPID (setting environment variables like `XUSER` and `DISPLAY`).

Note: If you have GNOME components running in your LXDE session (e.g. nautilus, various daemons) the session detection might go wrong. In these cases I would advise you to insert the code in the following way:

```
  if pidof x $PMS > /dev/null; then
     if [ -n $(pidof lxsession) ]; then
        for x in /tmp/.X11-unix/*; do
           displaynum=`echo $x | sed s#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##`
           getXuser;
           if [ x"$XAUTHORITY" != x"" ]; then
           export DISPLAY=":$displaynum"
           export _LXSESSION_PID=`pidof lxsession`
           killall lxsession-logout
           lxsession-logout
           fi
        done
        echo "if correct"
        exit
             else
                 exit
     fi
<...>
```

---

**Troubleshooting**

For some unknown reason these functions don't always work. In that case you will have to replace the snippet above with the following one:

```
if [ -n $(pidof lxsession) ]; then
   export DISPLAY=:0
   export _LXSESSION_PID=$(pidof lxsession)
   export XUSER=user
   export XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority
   lxsession-logout
   exit
fi
```

The environment variables are hard-coded in this one. Make sure to substitute `user` for your own user name. It should work for most single-user system configurations.

Here's another workaround, just in case none of the variants above work. Replace the `getXuser` function with the following passage:

```
getXuser() {
        user=`pinky -fw | awk '{ if ($2 == ":'$displaynum'" || $(NF) == ":'$displaynum'" ) { print $1; exit; } }'`
        if [ x"$user" = x"" ]; then
                startx=`pgrep -n startx`
                if [ x"$startx" != x"" ]; then
                        user=`ps -o user --no-headers $startx`
                fi
        fi
        if [ x"$user" = x"" ]; then                           # lines added
               user=$(pinky -fw | awk '{ print $1; exit; }')  # lines added
        fi                                                    # lines added
        if [ x"$user" != x"" ]; then
                userhome=`getent passwd $user | cut -d: -f6`
                export XAUTHORITY=$userhome/.Xauthority
        else
                export XAUTHORITY=""
        fi
        export XUSER=$user
}
```

**What does it do?**

The `powerbtn.sh` script is triggered by ACPID each time the power button is pressed. As you can see it already includes a number of checks for common DEs like Unity, GNOME and KDE. These checks are there to make sure that the shutdown event is handled by the respective power manager. Alas, LXDE doesn't have one of those built in.

That's why we added a snippet of our own that does the checking for ACPID. If it detects an LXDE session it makes sure that your PC isn't just shut down right away and instead launches the logout menu you should be familiar with.

With these changes you should now be able to launch your logout menu with your hardware power button - without needing to install a bulky power manager. And even better, this does not interfere with other DEs in any way.

**Sources**

http://www.ollie-reardon.co.uk/lxde-tip-power-button-not-working/

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acpid

http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=205

---

**Further reading**

[Lubuntu - power button doesn't turn off computer,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323103/lubuntu-power-button-doesnt-turn-off-computer?rq=1)

[Laptop power button not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193290/laptop-power-button-not-working?lq=1)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1008650

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87259/why-wont-this-shutdown-script-work-when-executed-by-acpid

Answer (score 1):

It seems that LXDE does not include the lxsession-logout package.
Install the package by typing this in terminal:

```
sudo apt install lxsession-logout
```

I know this is an old thread, but I just experienced this problem and could not find a direct answer anywhere.

Comment: Zanna - Yes, it did make the GUI power button work on my laptop.

Comment: I have `lxsession-logout` installed on my system but same facing same problem: power button does not do anything!

Answer (score 0):

**Using systemd.** Simply edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, uncomment the relevant line for `HandlePowerKey` and set to `poweroff`, `suspend`, or `hibernate` as desired. There are other preferences in there for the lid switch, etc.

[More info, options](https://cubethethird.wordpress.com/2016/11/13/configuring-the-power-button-in-gnome/)

---

**Without systemd.** This might get useless style points for using `w`, `pidof`, `read` and `ps` instead of piping through `sed`.

In `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`, before the final check and shutdown section.

```
# If LXDE is running execute lxsession-logout
IFS=" "
read -r user pid foo <<<$(ps u --no-headers -C lxsession)
if [ x"$user" != x"" ]; then
   read -r foo display foo <<<$(w -sh $user)
   if [ x"$XAUTHORITY" != x"" ]; then
       export DISPLAY="$display"
       export _LXSESSION_PID=$pid
       lxsession-logout
       exit
    fi
fi
```

**Troubleshooting.**

To troubleshoot, save this snippet as a script and (provided that you understand the commands and don't just blindly execute code off the internet) invoke it as root.